Displaying various/random loader messages one after another
I am building a content summarizer service using OpenAI API. However, the loading time is insane so I thought it would be cool to display a loader circle with some "funny" loader messages.
I use streamlit as a service so that I only have to specify some app.py file (at least this is what I do). Streamlit documentation is pretty straight forward while the service is also limiting one when it comes to UI. However, here is what I got:
import streamlit as st
import random

st.set_page_config(page_title="Content Sumamrizer", page_icon="icon.png", layout="wide")

st.title("Content Sumamrizer")
st.write("Catchy text")

url = st.text_input

loader_messages = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4"]

if st.button("Summarize"):
    with st.spinner(random.choice(loader_messages)):
        ...

I integrated st.spinner with a random selection from my specified loader_messages. Stuff works but since my loading time is sometimes around 15 seconds, I want to render every 4 seconds randomly one of the loader messages.
I was searching on the web but wasn't able so far to find anything that can provide an easy python solution (my expectation is some cool function that allows to print randomly a string with a duration time of 4 seconds until the loading process is finished).

You can do it with multiprocessing. It makes the heavy calculation compute while at the same time you can handle the spinner (I replaced the spinner by a simple string with a ⏳ emoji because I am using st.empty instead of st.spinner).
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

import streamlit as st

def heavy_computation():
    for _ in range(20):
        time.sleep(1)

st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Content Summarizer",
    page_icon="icon.png",
    layout="wide",
)

st.title("Content Summarizer")
st.write("Catchy text")

loader_messages = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4"]

if st.button("Summarize"):
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=heavy_computation)
    p1.start()

    # Handle the "spinner" part
    placeholder = st.empty()
    while True:
        if not p1.is_alive():  # This checks that the heavy_computation function has finished doing its work
            break
        message = random.choice(loader_messages)
        placeholder.text(f"⏳ {message}")
        time.sleep(4)

    p1.join()

    # This removes the last loader message displayed.
    placeholder.empty()

    st.write("✅ Heavy computation finished!")


Note that since I set a time.sleep(4), it can happen that the lines handling the change of messages will be a limiting factor (ie, your application will continue to update messages for nothing). Another way to do it would be to sleep(0.1) and check if the elapsed time since changing the message is long enough to trigger a change. This way, the spinner processing is not longer limiting.
...

    # Handle the "spinner"
    placeholder = st.empty()

    CHANGE_MESSAGE_INTERVAL = 8  # seconds
    elapsed = 0
    first = True
    t = time.time()
    while True:
        elapsed = elapsed + (time.time() - t)
        t = time.time()
        if first or elapsed > CHANGE_MESSAGE_INTERVAL:
            elapsed = 0
            first = False

            message = random.choice(loader_messages)
            placeholder.text(f"⏳ {message}")
            time.sleep(0.1)

        if not p1.is_alive():
            break

    p1.join()

...

